# How to associate connectivity intent to socket?

Tags: android, sockets, network-interface

On android...
Given a set of active sockets (<10),
My broadcast receiver gets an intent from the ConnectivityManager
indicating that a connection status has changed.
How do I associate the intent with the afflicted sockets?

I can get the NetworkInfo from the intent.

```
final ConnectivityManager cm = 
   (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final NetworkInfo netinfo = 
   ConnectivityManagerCompat.getNetworkInfoFromBroadcast(cm, aIntent);
```

This gives me the interface type.
I can also use the socket to get the NetworkInterface.

```
final InetAddress sourceAddr = socket.getLocalAddress();
final NetworkInterface ninterface = 
     NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(sourceAddr);
```

But I see no way to proceed from here.

Is there a way to get the NetworkInfo associated with a socket?

I am considering manually constructing a mapping 
between interface names and network types.
This mapping would be loaded curing initialization.
This is basically what I am doing visually when I run an ip or netstat command.